# elasticsearch must query combine OR?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been trying to use a must query with bool but I am failing to get the results.

In pseudo-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM info WHERE (ulevel= '1.3.10' or ulevel= '1.3.6') AND (@timestamp between '2017-06-05T07:00:00.000Z' and '2017-06-05T07:00:00.000Z')
```

Here is what I have:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                 "query_string": {
                        "default_field": "_all",
                        "query": "*"
                                    },
                 "range": {
                         "@timestamp": {
                               "from": "2017-06-05T07:00:00.000Z",
                               "to": "2017-06-05T07:20:00.000Z"
                                        }
                     },
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {"term": { "ulevel": "1.3.10"}},
                         {"term": { "ulevel": "1.3.6"}}
                             ]
                       }
            }
        ]
    }
  }
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your query looks correct. What's the mapping of your `ulevel` field?

Comment: "ulevel" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          }

Comment: Can you show a sample document that is supposed to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `terms` query for the first part and the range query for the second part

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "ulevel": [
              "1.3.10",
              "1.3.6"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "2017-06-05T07:00:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2017-06-05T07:20:00.000Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20
}
```

> Some Notes :
>
> 1. Filters documents that have fields that match any of the provided terms (**not analyzed**)
> 2. Also you can use some date spesific formulation with rage filter. Please check the range query page https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates more information.

Update:

Added `from` and `size` for comment question.

Comment: hkulekci,now can get the results , but why only get 10 document ? how to get all documents that match the filter ?

Comment: 10 document may be coz your 'size' field is 10. Increase the size if you want more documents. If number of documents is high, do pagination using scroll api or by using 'from' and 'size' fields.

Comment: Yes this is right. Please use `from` and `size` parameters. I will update my response.

Comment: hkulekci, but I don't know how many documents that match the filter ?It's possible to get all ?

Comment: You can see easily under `hits > total`. Elasticsearch returns you total matched document count.

Comment: hkulekci, so am I have to query for get  total hits first, then set the the total hits to size ? so I have to query two times , Am I right  ?

Comment: Hmm, I guess, you are triyng to get all the documents (this is not suggested). First option, you can use max number of from+size (which is 10000 by default and you can increase).  For example you have 5000 docs. You can use 9999. Second one is you should execute two query. One of them should be count query. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html Second one is search query.